# How in envoy show debugging info?

Tags: laravel-5, environment-variables

Working with envoy in laravel 5.7 I see in examples that echo command is used for debugging purpose.

But whe I write echo in my envoy file, like:

```
@setup
    $server_login_user= 'lardeployer';

    $timezone= 'Europe/Kiev';

    $path= '/var/www/html/AppDir';

    $current = $path . '/current';

    $repo= 'git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/votes.git'';

    $branch= 'master';

    echo "Step # 01";
    $writableDirs= [
        '/storage/logs',
        '/bootstrap/cache'
    ];
    echo "Step # 02";
    ...
    echo "Step # 03";

@endsetup

@servers(['production' => $server_login_user.'@NNN.NN.NN.N])


@task( 'clone', ['on'=>$on] )
    ...
```

running envoy script I do not see any echo messages in my console.

I see echo command mentioned in 5.0 version documentation : https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/envoy But that does not 
work in my 5.7/5.8 apps. Is echo still supported in laravel ? Or is that some config option ?

Thanks!

Comment: try this {{dd("Step # 01")}} also if you want echo try it between '@task @endtask'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are going to use echo you should use it inside tasks as mention on laravel too

> You may access the options in your tasks via Blade's "echo" syntax.
>   You may also use if statements and loops within your tasks.

for more detail click [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/envoy#variables)